# sending email in localhost via laravel 4.2 using gmail mail driver

Tags: php, email, laravel, laravel-4

im trying to send an email using laravel 4 and using the gmail mail driver i've already changed my `config/mail.php`file into something like this:

```
return array(

'driver' => 'smtp',

'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',

'port' => 587,

'from' => array('address' => 'email_that_im_using', 'name' => 'Trial'),

'encryption' => 'ssl',

'username' => 'mygmailusername',

'password' => 'mygmailpassword',

'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',

'pretend' => false,
```

);

and here is my code inside the controller

```
Mail::send('view', $data, function($message) 
            {
                $message->to(Input::get('SupplierEmail') , 'Jon Doe')->subject('Sample Mail!');
            });
```

im kinda lost on what will i put on the 'view' part and the $data part here is what my view looks like 
[image: my view]

and here is the code of my form inside my view

```
{{ Form::open(array('url' => 'addpurchorder')) }}
  <div class="form-group">
      {{ Form::label('module', 'Select Module: ') }}
      {{ Form::select('ModuleInfo', [null=>'Please Select Module'] + $modules , Input::old('ModuleInfo'), array('class'=>'form-control'))}}
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
      {{ Form::label('qty', 'Quantity') }}
      {{ Form::text('Quantity', Input::old('Quantity'), array('class' => 'form-control','placeholder' => 'Enter Quantity')) }}
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
      <h4><i><span class="label label-success">NOTE: Default Status is pending</span></i></h4>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
      {{ Form::label('from', 'School Email (From)') }}
      {{ Form::text('SchoolEmail', Input::old('SchoolEmail'), array('class' => 'form-control','placeholder' => 'Enter School Email')) }}
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
      {{ Form::label('to', 'Supplier Email (To)') }}
      {{ Form::text('SupplierEmail', Input::old('SupplierEmail'), array('class' => 'form-control','placeholder' => 'Enter Supplier Email')) }}
  </div>
   <div class="form-group">
      {{ Form::label('captcha', 'CAPTCHA image: ') }}
      </br>

      {{ HTML::image('http://localhost:8080/laravel3/app/captcha.php', 'alt' , array( 'width' => 250, 'height' => 43 )) }} </br></br>
      {{ Form::text('capt', Input::old('capt'), array('class' => 'form-control','placeholder' => 'enter generated captcha')) }}
  </div>

  {{ Form::submit('Create Purchase Order', array('class' => 'btn btn-primary')) }}

{{ Form::close()}}
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a route that maps to a controller:

```
Route::post('addpurchorder', 'PurchaseController@doStuff');
```

Then add your validation, and mailer function above to the `doStuff` method.

Answer (score 1):

The `view` is the template that is be used for the email's body.

http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/mail gives more information about how to do it.

your view file can look like this:

```
<body>
    Hello {{ $data->name }}
</body>
```